# About the extreme value theorem over the extended real line

Tags: calculus

This problem might seem very elementary to someone. I am using the following arguments. I would like to make sure that it is right.

---

Let $f$ be a continuous function defined on $R$. If $\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}f(x)$ exists, then $f$ is a continuous function over the extended real line $R\cup\{\pm\infty\}$. Then we can say that there exists $x\in R\cup\{\pm\infty\}$ such that

$$
f(y) \le f(x), \qquad \forall y\in R.
$$

---

The usual extreme value theorem is stated over a compact set $[a,b]$; see the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem).

Thank you very much!

Anand

Comment: The extended real line is compact.  Open neighborhoods of $-\infty$ contain a set $(-\infty, x)$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and similar for $+\infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument works, because the extended real line is compact: $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty,-\infty\}$ with the natural order topology is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$. An explicit homeomorphism is

$$h(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac12+\frac1\pi\arctan x,&\text{if }x\in\mathbb{R}\\\\
1,&\text{if }x=\infty\\
0,&\text{if }x=-\infty\;.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks Brian M. Scott. :-)