# How $ [- \infty,x], x \in \mathbb{R} $ is always compact in extended real line with order topology?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

How $ [- \infty,x], x \in \mathbb{R} $ is  compact in extended real line with order topology?

Comment: From an open cover, pick one open set covering $\infty$. This contains some $[\infty,y)$, so you are left with $[y,x]$, if that helps

Comment: but why is $[y,x]$ compact in order topology? I know that i can say it is compact but in euclidean topology

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/113769/721644).

Answer (score 1):

A set $X$ is compact in the order topology iff every subset has a supremum, or equivalently: both $\min(X), \max(X)$ exist (as they do here, $-\infty$ and $x$) and every non-empty subset has a supremum (which is clear from the order proprties of $\Bbb R$), so yes it is.

Alternatively you could show it is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$.

Comment: $arctan$ extended to $\mathbb{R}^*$ would be an easy homeomorphism to $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$.